# DotPlot with Gradient Background in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I wanted to ask help in order to make a **dotplot** in **python** with a **gradient palette AS BACKGROUND**. I managed to do this plot in R (which I have some expertise), but for learning purposes **I want to make it in Python**.

This is the plot made by me in R, which I want to reproduce in Python:

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqbJ1.jpg*

This is the table used to generate the plot in R

```
Player,Rank
Messi,3
Neymar,3
Ronaldo,2
Iniesta,2
Rooney,2
Pogba,2
Dybala,1
Bale,0
```

And this is my attemp in Python using Matplotlib, seaborn and pandas:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

fit = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=',')

sns.set(
        font_scale=1.6, 
        context="paper", 
        rc={'grid.color':'black', 'axes.edgecolor':'black'})

g = sns.PairGrid(fit,
                 y_vars=["Player"], x_vars=["Rank"],
                 size=3, aspect=0.9, 
                 palette=dict(Reactividad="black"))

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=12, orient="h",
  edgecolor="black")

g.set(xlim = (-0.3,3.3), xticks=[0,1,2,3])
```

This block code gave me as a result the following plot:

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ0Ur.jpg*

The question here is:

**How to do to plot a gradient like "RdYlGn_r" palette into the plot?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a simple background image.

To get started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
n = len(names)
gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 100).reshape(1, -1)
plt.imshow(gradient , extent=[-0.25, 3.25, -1, n], aspect='auto', cmap='RdYlGn_r')
sns.stripplot(x=values, y=names, color='b', size=12, edgecolor='b')
plt.hlines(np.arange(0, n), -0.25, 3.25, linestyles='--', linewidth=1)
plt.grid(False)
plt.xlim(-0.25, 3.25)
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

[image]

Comment: Have a question: whats the meaning of **reshape(1, -1)**? I cannot understand why to reshape

Comment: `linspace` creates a 1D array but `plt.imshow` needs a 2D image. Thus, I reshaped it into a (1x100) 2D array for plotting as an image (-1 in reshape means automatic size). Maybe just adding a new axis is easier to understand: `gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)[np.newaxis, :]`